Multiple NuGet packages referencing a common class library in the same solution
I have a single Visual Studio solution with multiple .NET Standard 2.0 C# class library projects:
MainSolution
---- ClassLibA
---- ClassLibB
---- CommonClassLib

ClassLibA and ClassLibB are both going to be NuGet packages to be consumed later by other apps. CommonClassLib is a common utilty class library that has stuff to be used by each other class libraries (think configuration class for SOAP Service wrappers). I want to be able to deploy a NuGet package for ClassLibA that has the functionality in CommonClassLib without anything from ClassLibB and vice versa.
I attempted to follow this post, to no avail: https://dev.to/yerac/include-both-nuget-package-references-and-project-reference-dll-using-dotnet-pack-2d8p. I would get a SYSLIB1102 error and I was completely lost since we are using the same target framework.
Do namespaces matter in this case? Is it something else? Any help would be great.
For added complexity in a separate but related issue, I want to deploy a JSON config file with the CommonClassLib that the consuming application can have to configure how the packages will behave, and I am looking for help with that too.

Why don't you make CommonClassLib into a nuget package, too?

I suppose I could, just seems like I should be able to wrap it into a single package with A and B.

Why? If you don't create a third package, you'd be distributing exactly the same binary in 2 different packages, which might cause some funny issues if you don't keep versions of ClassLibA and ClassLibB perfectly aligned when you reference both of them.

Visual Studio makes this kind of thing pretty straightforward if you know what levers to pull. So, let's say that for demo purposes we make a console app named nuget-dependencies that happens to use the ClassLibA nuget which is dependent on the CommonClassLib nuget. So here's what I wish someone had told me, in hopes it gets things moving in the right direction for you.



The three NuGet projects are similar, so let's just look at the csproj file for ClassLibA shown in full below.
This tag makes it build to an adhoc folder relative to the solution:
<PackageOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\local-repo</PackageOutputPath>
This causes it to pack the NuGets whenever the project builds.
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
And this is a floating reference to "the latest release version" of CommonClassLib.
<PackageReference Include="CommonClassLib" Version="*" />
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <Title>ClassLibA</Title>
        <Description>Demo Only</Description>
        <PackageTags>portable;net;android;ios</PackageTags>
        <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/IVSoftware/nuget-dependencies</RepositoryUrl>
        <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/IVSoftware/nuget-dependencies</PackageProjectUrl>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <AssemblyVersion>1.5.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <Authors>IVSoft</Authors>
        <Owner>IVSoft</Owner>
        <Copyright>Copyright © 2024 IVSoft</Copyright>
        <FileVersion>$(AssemblyVersion)</FileVersion>
        <Version>$(AssemblyVersion)</Version>
        <PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
        <PackageLicenseExpression>MIT</PackageLicenseExpression>
        <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>True</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
        <!--SignAssembly>True</SignAssembly-->
        <!--AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile></AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile-->
        <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
        <PackageOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\local-repo</PackageOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="..\README.md">
            <Pack>True</Pack>
            <PackagePath>\</PackagePath>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="CommonClassLib" Version="*" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>


Now build and inspect the local-repo folder:

And connect to it using the settings gear of the Package Source drop down.


The main point I want to make regarding your question is that when you go to manage the NuGet packages for the console app, one would only need to install the ClassLibA (or the ClassLibB...) and the common library will be picked up as a transitive reference.


And as you stated ClassLibA and ClassLibB know nothing of each other. That said, if you were to use both A and B in a project, and the versions were different, then you would resolve this by an explicit reference to the common NuGet in the client project. (Since you are the publisher of all three packages however, this is not as likely as when third-party packages reference different versions of something like SQLite or JSON.)

Clone
